# Replace NTFS hardlinks with files

Tags: ntfs, duplicate, hardlink

I deduplicated backup files on an NTFS partition. I would like to know if there is a way to reduplicate the files so that they can be edited individually.

Current:

```
/dir1/file1
/dir2/file1 -- hard link to /dir1/file1
```

Desired:

```
/dir1/file1
/dir2/file1 -- not a hard link
```

Answer (score 3):

Just make a copy the file, then delete the file and rename:

In dir2:

```
copy file1 tmp
del file1
ren tmp file1
```